# PHP Results inside string

Tags: php, shortcode

Putting PHP results inside a string for shortcode use.

```
function endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
    // search forward starting from end minus needle length characters
    return $needle === "" || (($temp = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $temp) !== FALSE);
}

$lastDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('today - 30 days'));
$todayDate = date('Y-m-d');

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `wp_statistics_pages` WHERE id=1428 AND `date` BETWEEN '$lastDate' AND '$todayDate' ", ARRAY_A );
for($i=0;$i<count($results);$i++)
if (endsWith(get_site_url().''.$results[$i]['uri'], 'http://universitycompare.com/universities/the-uni-of-westminster/')) {
   echo $results[$i]['count'].',';  }
```

I want the results that are are being echoed out ($results[$i]['count'].',') to be $newstring so I can use them in the below shortcode. (See $newstring in use below).

```
<?php 
echo do_shortcode('[wp_charts title="linechart" canvaswidth="976px" canvasheight="244px" relativewidth="4" width="976px" height="244px" type="line" align="alignright" datasets="' . $newstring . '"]'); 
?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and how did that work out (any error messages)?

Comment: So, you need `if (endsWith(get_site_url().''.$results[$i]['uri'], 'http://universitycompare.com/universities/the-uni-of-westminster/')) {
   $newstring = $results[$i]['count']; echo $newstring.',';  }`, what is the problem?

Comment: I have no errors, when I run the script, it prints the data. When I echo $newstring; it comes out with just the last number as to appose the entire list.

Comment: @AlanMachado - see this example: http://universitycompare.com/analytics-test/ The last number is 88 of the data.

Comment: @Risadinha - Would you know how to fix the echo'ing of all data instead of the last value?